# Show Value instead of id in Create View with SelectList in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on Asp.Net Core application. I have 4 tables that are related.

City, Street, House and AlarmInstalls

The app is for managing Alarm Instalations.

House belongs to a street and to a City They are related. House has a DoorNr atribute...

When i try to create a new alarm install. It is showing me the houses i have available by Id, but i need it to show the full address. the problem is that the house class only has the StreetId(from Street Class) and DoorNr. How can i manage to get it to show the full Address?

```
            public partial class AlarmInstall
            {
                public int AlarmInstallId { get; set; }
                public int HouseId { get; set; }
                public string Model { get; set; }

                public virtual House House { get; set; }
            }

            public partial class House
            {
                public House()
                {
                    AlarmInstall = new HashSet<AlarmInstall>();
                }

                public int HouseId { get; set; }
                public int StreetId { get; set; }
                public string DoorNr { get; set; }
                public int CityId { get; set; }

                public virtual City City { get; set; }
                public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<AlarmInstall> AlarmInstall { get; set; }
            }

            public partial class Street
            {
                public Street()
                {
                    House = new HashSet<House>();
                }

                public int StreetId { get; set; }
                public string StreetName { get; set; }

                public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
            }

            public partial class City
            {
                public City()
                {
                    House = new HashSet<House>();
                }

                public int CityId { get; set; }
                public string CityName { get; set; }

                public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
            }
```

My AlarmsInstallController has the following code:

```
            // GET: AlarmInstalls/Create
            public IActionResult Create()
            {
                ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "HouseId", "HouseId");
                return View();
            }

            // POST: AlarmInstalls/Create

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("AlarmInstallId,HouseId,Model")] AlarmInstall alarmInstall)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(alarmInstall);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "HouseId", "DoorNr", alarmInstall.HouseId);
                return View(alarmInstall);
            }
```

And my View has the following code:

```
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="HouseId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.HouseId"></select>
                </div>
```

This is my SelectList for HouseId...

```
            ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "HouseId", "HouseId");
```

I need to show the full address, Composed of the streetName (from StreetClass) and DoorNr, instead of HouseId, what should i change in my code?

Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by myself with the help of google...

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //   ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "HouseId", "HouseId");

        var fullAddress = _context.House
                            .Select(h => new { HouseId = h.HouseId, FullAddress = h.Street.StreetName
                           + ", " + h.DoorNr })
                            .ToList();

        ViewBag.HouseId = new SelectList(fullAddress, "HouseId", "FullAddress");
```